# .htaccess not working in amazon ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

I have a server from amazon's ec2 service running on Linux Ubuntu ( 
Ubuntu Server 13.04 64 bit)  and I have installed apache, php, and mysql. I have added a .htaccess file in my document root (i.e /var/www/).

Here is the code in .htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

If I remove .php from url like "index1" instead of "index1.php", it returns 404 browser error. It works properly in my previous server.

I have .htaccess enabled in server. I did it using command "sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/default" and changed "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All".

I have also checked .htaccess working by passing invalid value in htaccess file and it returns "Internal server error - 500" in browser.

Here is the link of my server information : `http://54.200.58.45/mytest.php`

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because the rewrite module doesn’t come enabled by default for security reasons.

Create a new file called `rewrite.conf` in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`
in the file put this line `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Now reload server `sudo service apache2 restart`

This worked for me and hopefully for you, but I don’t advice this for production servers. This is information for regular Ubuntu users not for a live server.

Comment: A couple of questions for a non 'regular Ubuntu user' ....What would be the approach for a live server? What risks are in the above? Thx!

Comment: not worked for me.. putty return module_rewrite is already loaded skipping

Answer (score 12):

This is wat worked for me on a fresh EC2 instance with Ubuntu 13.10:

- a2enmod rewrite
- vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
- add the following to the VirtualHost

```
<Directory "/var/www">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

- service apache2 restart

Answer (score 2):

The problem is by default in apache installed on Ubuntu doesn't have .htaccess enabled so first you have to manually enable it in a config file and restart apache.

Here are the steps.

1) Login to your EC2 instance with SSH.

**ssh -i "Yourkey.pem" ubuntu@yourpublicip**

2) Enable Mode Rewrite, this is just incase if it's not enabled.

**sudo a2enmod rewrite**

3) Go to the following directory.

**cd /etc/apache2/sites-available**

If you use LS command here you will see the following file.

**000-default.conf**

That's the file with default apache configuration which is applied to your sites in */var/www/html* folder.

4) Open this file for editing.

**sudo nano 000-default.conf**

5) Add following lines after DocumentRoot /var/www/html line.

**Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All


     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all**

6) Save the file and restart the apache.

**sudo service apache2 restart**

that's it and now your .htaccess file will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the mod rewrite module is enabled or not first.

Comment: I have used "sudo a2enmod rewrite" to enable mod rewrite but it shows that "Module rewrite already enabled".

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything and nothing worked...

2 hours later.. Finally fixed it.

So first the things to rule out.

1. Make sure that you have made the changes in **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** and in /**etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf** that everyone is talking about... (AllowOverride All and AccessFileName .htaccess must not be commented out)
2. Make sure that the Directory /var/www/html is pointing to the right folder. Some times it has /html and some times it's just /var/www (however it must not end in / i think, but that might not matter.)

   3. Finally, and this is what worked for me. Restart the whole server, not just Apache. I figured out that this was my problem, after i tried stopping apache2 (s**ervice apache2 stop**) and I was still able to access my website. So I did a full reboot and then all the changes I have been making for the last 2 hours, finally kicked in.

Success :)