# How to enable .htaccess in amazon ec2 running ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2

I have an instance running ubuntu in ec2. I have this .htaccess file :-

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This file is located inside the `var/www/html` folder. I am aiming to achieve loading of `amazon-public-dns.com/index.php` as `amazon-public-dns.com/index`. 
Now, I have tried these steps :-

1)
 Creating the `rewrite.conf` in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` and in the file putting the line `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so`. ([Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19568145/3247497))

2)
 Running the command `apache2 enable module rewrite`. Also, in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and writing this in the end :-

```
 <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        # changed from None to FileInfo
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Note that [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/48363) told to edit the `default`. But, since that file was not there in my case, I edited the `000-default.conf` file.

I restarted apache as told. But the link `amazon-public-dns.com/index` gives me a 404 :( Please help me.
**EDIT** : I put some random junk in the htaccess file. But the index.php is not giving any 500 internal server error which means that the htaccess file is being ignored. Now in

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles

, they say to enable htaccess edit this file - `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`. **BUT THERE IS NO SUCH FILE**

Comment: if you are still looking for the answer, this should help you, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61009/how-to-enable-use-of-htaccess-in-apache-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

following command works for me Great !

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To check loaded modules

```
sudo apache2ctl -M
```

Answer (score 1):

The default conf file /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf only work if its having a symlink in sites-enabled folder.

You have done all right steps. Its may be problem of sysmlink of sites-available folder. You can either create a symlink or update 000-default.conf with `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` inside file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced this exact same problem on an ubuntu EC2 instance.

This worked for me:

Place your `.htaccess` configuration inside the `<IfModule ..>` directive:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # your config here
</IfModule>
```

Not sure if `/var/www/html` is actually taken into account by the server.
Try changing this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    # your current implementation
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

for this one:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    # your current implementation
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

This directive should already by there in your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

If that does not work try to comment out your configuration, particularly the part that has the `allow,deny` and `allow from all`

```
<Directory /var/www>
    # your current implementation
    AllowOverride All
    # Order allow,deny # try to comment this one out 
    # allow from all # also this one
</Directory>
```

Last but not least, check that the rewrite `a2enmod` module is loaded as suggested by @kamal-kumar and do not forget to restart you apache.

This worked for me, hope this helps someone else :)